# DUnit Testing in a Midas/DataSnap project

Tags: delphi, datasnap, dunit, midas-server

How does one setup DUnit Testing in a Midas/DataSnap project in Delphi 2006

Edit

How does one set up a Dunit Test into a TRemoteDataModule 
The project wizard in Delphi 2006 does not work with TRemoteDataModule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question doesn't entirely make sense.  Unit tests are performed in a separate project, not within your DataSnap server. Generally, tests which connect to a database are integration tests rather than unit tests.  What is it, exactly that you want to test?  If it's utility methods within, say, a TRemoteDataModule, you should extract those out into a separate class as class methods, and test them there.  You should not have to instantiate an application server to perform unit tests.

Comment: I don't agree. Unit testing a Client/Server application with real Client/Server communication, multiple clients and multi processing is mandatory, IMHO. It's sometimes called "stress tests", and it's always worth it...

Comment: @A.Bouchez, where did I say that you shouldn't do integration tests? I didn't; you absolutely *should* do integration tests. But unit tests are different than integration tests!

Comment: @Craig agreed, however DUnit can be used to perform integration tests and I have not seen a Delphi tool yet which is specifically designed for automated integration tests

Comment: @mjn, we use TestComplete for this.

Comment: I agree with Craig. A test is not a unit test if it talks to a database, the file system, the network or any service beyond your application's control.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the terse answer above, the iPad posts whenever I hit return while editing a post.

dUnit is designed to perform unit testing, and what you are trying to do is NOT unit testing.

A test is not a unit test if:

- It talks to the database
- It communicates across the network
- It touches the file system
- It can't run at the same time as any of your other unit tests
- You have to do special things to your environment (such as editing config files) to run it.
- It can't run in isolation

If you follow the SOLID principles (especially the single responsibility principle), using dUnit to test your class (without testing the Midas/DataSnap related logic) should be reasonably simple.  And really, you shouldn't need to test the Midas/DataSnap logic.

But there are ways to perform integration and behavioural tests on Delphi applications.

Personally, I wouldn't use TestComplete because it doesn't integrate well with any sort of CI server and the tests are stored in a proprietary binary format (which makes merging differences or maintaining changes in any source control system problematic).

You could try [dSpec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dspec/), but I'm not sure Jody Dawkins is maintaining it any more.

I have used the [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) BASIC scripting language directly on some projects, and also used its .NET assembly to drive a Delphi application using NUnit and C# on another.  While not perfect, the NUnit / C# solution was more elegant than anything I'd seen for performing functional / behavioural testing Delphi applications.  It did take some effort to get it setup though.